# can I use dc 12v motor in kerosene?

Tags: motor

I do want to run a motor under kerosene, before to that I want to know that will it be dangerous or not?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you need a fuel pump or a 12V motor that just happens to be located under a tank of kerosene (which is generally not advised)?

Comment: There's a risk of sparks, which might not be a good idea around kerosene (assuming there is also oxygen nearby, which there usually is on earth). An AC motor would be safer, but I'd still avoid submerging electronics in fuel oils. The kerosene might also be able to dissolve some plastics used in the motor's construction, too.

Comment: it is 12v dc motor only, i need to rotate it in kerosene. i don't have any idea regarding these motors  to analyze the situation, so could you please explain me what will happen if it will be immersed in kerosene?

Comment: This question is more about what it takes to ignite kerosene. I don't know what field of engineering covers this, but it's not EE.

Comment: actually kerosene is a dielectric. so, my doubt is, will it fire for those sparks which will be generating over there? if it is oxygen free environment inside the tank, the usage will be possible or not?

Comment: i would think that it is not dangerous as long as the motor stays competely submerged ... any exposure to air while the motor is energized could prove to be disastrous ... of course, if the motor is designed for use in explosive atmosphere, then it should be safe

Answer (score 6):

There are many 12v fuel pumps that are designed to run submerged in gasoline, like this one for example [https://www.amazon.com/WALBRO-255LPH-PRESSURE-GSS342-Authentic/dp/B0098MC3GU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0098MC3GU)

You should look into pumps specifically designed to be used with fuels; there may be ones specifically rated for kerosene.